# Use Cypress functions on variables

Tags: cypress

I'm looping throw all of the `.row` and need to grab the inner elements within `.row`. Is there a way to do this? I wasn't able to find any documentation on this on Cypress' website.

```
let num = 0
cy.get('.row').each(row => { 
  let rowDiv = cy.get(row).get('div') // not correct
  let rowBtn = cy.get(row).get('button') // not correct

  cy.get(rowDiv).should('have.text', 'Task ' + num)
  cy.get(rowBtn).should('have.text', "Btn ' + num)

  num++
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can use `cy.wrap()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap) to turn the yielded JQuery elements back into Cypress Chainables. Additionally, `cy.each()` can yield you the index of the current iteration, so instead of having to use `num`, you could just use that index variable.

```js
cy.get('.row')
  .each((row, rowIndex) => { // yields JQuery element and current iteration
    cy.wrap(row).find('div').should('have.text', `Task ${rowIndex}`);
    cy.wrap(row).find('button').should('have.text', `Btn ${rowIndex}`);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! I just had to change .get to .find in your solution

Comment: Ahh my bad, copy and paste error. I'll update answer.